# How to save a session with open programs and files?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, startup, session

How can I reproduce the current session, including open programs and files on my Ubuntu 11.04 laptop and rebooting?

I've got a bunch of windows open in Chromium and Firefox (this is probably the easy part), `emacs`, `gnome-terminal`, a `pdf` open in evince, `mplayer` paused, `virtualbox` manager and `skype` running.